# Determine the present value of a perpetual annuity

Tags: calculus, economics

I want to determine the present value of a perpetual annuity, which will incur an interest payment of € 1 at the end of each year;

A calculative interest rate $r$ is assumed.

We are at the time $t = 0$, the first payout is in $t = 1$.

$$$$

Could you maybe give me a hint about how we could calculate it?

Is it maybe  $1+r\cdot t$ ?

Comment: 1) PV of a cashflow is the sum of PV of individual payment of that cashflow.
2) PV of $1$€ today = PV of $(1+r)$€ one year from now $= \cdots = $ PV of $(1+r)^n$€ $n$ year from now.

Comment: Ah ok.... The given $t$ is in your formula the $n$ ? I found in wikipedia the following: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetuity#Detailed_description ] they use an other formula, or not? @achillehui

Comment: When for example $r=8\%$ then is the PV equal to $1+0.08=1+0.08$ ? @achillehui

Comment: For $r = 8$% p.a. If you receive a $1$€  at $n$ year from now, the PV of that  1€  in future is $(1+0.08)^{\color{red}{-}n}$€.  For cashflow with duration less than a year, interest rate is typically quoted as simple interest rate. For cashflow longer than a year, interest rate is quoted as compound interest rate. Since we are dealing with a perpetual annuity, the interest rate should be interpreted as a compound one.

Comment: I got stuck right now... At the end of each year we give $1$ euro, right? What exactly is a calculative interest rate? @achillehui

Comment: @MaryStar Have you got an answer to this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume that you are the *owner* of the annuity, and that you *receive* the payment of 1 € at the end of each year. The *issuer* of the annuity will have to *pay* this amount. We assume that the interest rate is fixed at $r$, and we use this value for all calculations; this is the meaning of the term calculative interest rate. (In real life, interest rates will go up and down, which introduce uncertainty into the calculations.)

The present value of the first payment is $1\over 1+r$, since that is what the issuer will have to set aside today in order to make the payment at time $t=1$. The present value of the second payment is $1\over (1+r)^2$, which the issuer sets aside today for the payment of 1 € at time $t=2$. Continuing in the same minner, the present value of the perpetual annuity is the sum of the infinite geometric series
$${1\over 1+r}+{1\over (1+r)^2}+\dots={1\over 1+r}{1\over 1-{1\over 1+r}}={1\over r}$$
If you were to receive $A$ € each year, all terms above are multiplied by $A$, and the present value becomes $A\over r$, in agreement with the formula in [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetuity#Detailed_description).

Answer (score 0):

Let denote the annuity denote as $a$ and the interest rate as $r$. If the annuity incur an interest of 1€ per year  then $a\cdot r=1$.

You receive an amount of a€ for $n$  periods. The present value of that payments is

$PV=\frac{a}{q^n}\cdot \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} q^i=\frac{a}{q^n}\cdot \frac{1-q^n}{1-q} \quad$ with $q=1+r$

$=\frac{a}{q^n}\cdot \frac{1}{1-q}-\frac{a}{q^n}\cdot \frac{q^n}{1-q} =\frac{a}{q^n}\cdot \frac{1}{1-q}- \frac{a}{1-q}= \frac{a}{q^n}\cdot \frac{1}{1-q}+ \frac{a}{q-1}$

Now  $n$ goes to infinity.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \frac{a}{q^n}\cdot \frac{1}{1-q}+\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{a}{q-1} $$

$=0+\frac{a}{q-1}$

with $q=1+r$ we get

$PV=\frac{a}{1+r-1}=\frac{a}r$

With $a\cdot r=1$

$PV=a^2$ or $PV=\frac1{r^2}$

Comment: This is not correct; you are using $a$ with two different meanings.

Comment: My definition of a is the annuity.

Comment: Then I think you are misinterpreting the question. To me, an annuity is a contract, not a number. The two numbers associated with this annuity are the present value and the yearly payment. Obviously, the yearly payment of this annuity is 1 €.

Comment: The value of an annuity is a fix number. You pay in a fix amount of $a$. The present value of a perpetual annuity is $\frac{a}r$. But if you have a better idea please post an answer.